# How to work with many REST services using Forms Authentication in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, iis, cookies

I am trying my hand at securing content for a website by using RESTful WCF services (plural) with Forms Authentication through IIS 7.0.

I've been researching how this can be done for the past week, and while I have come across a number of samples and short tutorials, none of them have described how to invoke services independent of one another within a full-scale website or basic HTML page in detail beyond short snippets.

Following instructions that have been repeated across many of the tutorials, I was able to construct a console app and get the services functioning with Forms Authentication.

I believe the part *I am stuck on is actually transferring the cookie created by the authenticator to the other services*.  Using Fiddler, I can see the authenticator response returning a Forms Authentication Ticket in cookie form.  But services calls do not show the cookie in the requests.  And since the cookie is marked HttpOnly, I can't grab it in javascript to force the cookie in the request header for all other services.

Below is the RESTful WCF service I have stored on IIS and am using to test.  I could really use 50 extra pairs of eyes to see what I am missing.

Thank you for your time.

**TestServiceC.svc**

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class ServiceC : IServiceC
    {
        public string Foobar()
        { 
            return "Hello!  You have access to ServiceC.";
        }
    }
```

**FormsAuthenticator.svc**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)] 
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    private User user;

    /// <summary>
    /// I validate credentials against database, then I am creating custom cookie, encrypting it and sending back to the client.  
    /// I have to use ASP.NET compatibility mode to enable HttpContext and related functionality.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Login(User testUser)
    {
        bool isAuthenticated = false;
        var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(testUser.UserName, false);

        isAuthenticated = AuthenticateUser(testUser.UserName, testUser.Password);

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    ticket.Version,
                    testUser.UserName,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    true,
                    user.UserID.ToString()
                );

            cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(testUser.UserName, false);
        }

        return isAuthenticated;
    }
```

**Web.config** for TestServiceC.svc but very similar to the one in FormsAuthenticator.svc

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <machineKey validationKey="32E35872597989D14CC1D5D9F5B1E94238D0EE32CF10AA2D2059533DF6035F4F"
                decryptionKey="B179091DBB2389B996A526DE8BCD7ACFDBCAB04EF1D085481C61496F693DF5F4"
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".MABFORMSAUTH2" domain=".localhost" timeout="30" protection="All" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <!-- This is the defining instruction that determines if a cookie is required in order to use a service.-->
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RESTBinding" allowCookies="true">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TestServiceC.ServiceC">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RESTBinding" contract="TestServiceC.IServiceC" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, x-requested-with,content-type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```